# How can I synchronize two PaintEventArgs?

Tags: c#

I have a Form that contains a picturebox (in which a bitmap is drawn that is updated via "pictureBox1.Invalidate")
Inside the Form (in a lower right corner) a circle is drawn that at the beginning is colored red and according to a logic turns green ("this.Invalidate ()").
If I comment pictureBox1.Invalidate and leave this.Invalidate () the LED changes color as required but does not update the bitmap inside the picturebox (Obviously vice versa)
I want both to be updated at the same time.
How can I do???

```
    // THIS METHOD ALLOWS YOU TO DRAW A BITMAP INSIDE A PICTUREBOX THAT IS LOCATED WITHIN A FORM
 private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Nuitrack.Update(_skeletonTracker);
            }
            catch (LicenseNotAcquiredException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LicenseNotAcquired exception. Exception: ", exception);
                throw exception;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nuitrack update failed. Exception: ", exception);
            }

            //Draw bitmap
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bitmap.Bitmap, new Point(0, 0));

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

// THIS METHOD ALLOWS YOU TO DRAW A LED ON THE FORM
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnPaint(args);
            // Update Nuitrack data. Data will be synchronized with skeleton time stamps.
            try
            {
                Nuitrack.Update(_skeletonTracker);
            }
            catch (LicenseNotAcquiredException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LicenseNotAcquired exception. Exception: ", exception);
                throw exception;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nuitrack update failed. Exception: ", exception);
            }

            // Draw LED
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
            args.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 565, 502, 45, 45);

            //LED is Red
            args.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 565, 502, 45, 45);

            // Draw skeleton joints
            if (_skeletonData != null)
            {
                foreach (var skeleton in _skeletonData.Skeletons)
                {
                    //LED becomes Green                   
                    args.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 565, 502, 45, 45);                  
                }
            }
            //Update Form
           //this.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Unclear question. In any case: __Never__ call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` inside of `pictureBox1_Paint` !!! Also: Is there any pbox.Image involved or only stuff you draw onto it?